# Genesis 34, what are the judgement of the Torah regarding the action of Simeon and Levi?

Tags: genesis

Genesis 34, the rape of Dinah, daughter of Jacob, and the reaction of her brothers to the act of Sichem the son of Hemor the Hevite.

What are the judgement of the Torah regarding the action of Dinah brothers: Simeon and Levi regarding using circumcision of the Hemors as a means to take revenge of them. And killing all the Hemors, who were trying to appease the family of Jacob, and were trying to fix the situation.

How the scholars of the Bible justified the killing of the Hemors?

Answer (score 1):

Here a couple of quick thoughts.

- Historical narratives record what happened, often without passing judgment
- The Torah wasn't written until hundreds of years after these events
- Jacob, their father, condemned their behavior on his deathbed, but because what they did put the entire family at risk, and they did it without his consent

Generally, the *Genesis* narratives are brutally frank that Jacob and his sons behaved in ungodly way at times. Looking back, this seems to reflect God's grace and eternal purpose in choosing them, in spite of their all too human behavior.